# Main domain working but not subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, hosting, cpanel, dns-record

I modified my dns record with my hosting provider in order to settle a subdomain, and they asked me to wait 24 hours to 48 for propagation while the TTL is 1 hour. (the ip adress in the picture below belong to my cpanel server )

Here is a screenshot showing the result. Please, if any expert is here, tell me if you spot a mistake.
Because whenever i try to access it after 1 or 2 hour i have the error : DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
Does that error belong to DNS propagation ?
Is it normal ?
Before touching dns record with my godaddy support, we had '' name not resolved error''

Thank you for your answer ! don't hesitate to ask me for more !

[Dns record on godaddy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/539dH.jpg)

---

@Michael Hampton, i tried what you said but i don't want to mess with dns record, so here's a trial screenshot photoshoped, what do you think ?
please be more clear, what do you mean with www A record
I have a cname with the name of www, not an A record.Should i remove the A record with @ ?

And whenever i try to make a cname with Trial and an A record with Trial name, i can't because they have the same name, so what should i do ? remove the A record with Trial or modify it ? Please be more clear to bring efficient solutions and thank you for your help !

[image: Trial dns updated according to michael hampton]

Answer (score 3):

Your DNS entry is working, it's just not the one you want.

You configured a DNS entry for `trial.example.com.example.com`.

If you want `trial.example.com` you only should add `trial` in the `Nom` field.

Comment: On the other hand, your CNAME entry works for me.

Comment: In addition www subdomain is a cname referencing itself. Valid, but probably not what you want.

Comment: Edit : Thank you Gerald for your answer. i contacted the technical support and they made these changes : [Updated DNS record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZrx9.png) What do you think, is it good ? They changed the A record to trial but in the other hand they added the whole url in the Cname.

Comment: thank you vidarlo for your comment. i'm reading all of your comment. The technical support wasn't able to help me as you do all. I will never forget your help, all of you. 
Internet is such a fantastic place

Comment: @zack These are not the good records. You should have a CNAME for the name `trial` with the value `@`, and you should have no record for the name `trial.qubemarket.com`. To make future maintenance easier, you also should not have the A record for `www`, but instead a CNAME to value `@`.

Comment: I answered your comment below with a screenshot Michael, please go see it, i need your help !